# CDI SessionScoped Bean results in two instances in same session

Tags: jsf, cdi

I've got two instances of a SessionScoped CDI bean for the same session.   I was under the impression that there would be one instance generated for me by CDI, but it generated two.  Am I misunderstanding how CDI works, or did I find a bug?

Here is the bean code:

```
package org.mycompany.myproject.session;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Named @SessionScoped public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String myField = null;

    public MyBean() {
        System.out.println("MyBean constructor called");

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        String sessionId = session.getId();
        System.out.println("Session ID: " + sessionId);
    }

    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }

    public void setMyField(String myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}
```

Here is the Facelet code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.myField}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here is the output from deployment and navigating to page:

```
INFO: Loading application org.mycompany_myproject_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT at /myproject
INFO: org.mycompany_myproject_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT was successfully deployed in 8,237 milliseconds.
INFO: MyBean constructor called
INFO: Session ID: 175355b0e10fe1d0778238bf4634
INFO: MyBean constructor called
INFO: Session ID: 175355b0e10fe1d0778238bf4634
```

Using GlassFish 3.0.1

Comment: I was actually alerted to the above problem by a related one: calling a non-final method in a constructor (or initializer block) causes unintended effects with CDI. I've since read that using a non-final method is not advised (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). If I use a non-final method to intialize a List in a CDI bean then the intitializer is called twice! Note: CDI doesn't allow final methods and will throw a Runtime Exception stating that the bean is not proxyable.  The "fix" is to not call the non-final method and do all work in the initilizer block.

Comment: I've noticed that if I define an init method annotated with @PostConstruct that it is only called once (despite two instances of the bean being created). I'm guessing that CDI is creating a pool of instances of my bean and calls post construct as it pulls them out of the pool.  I guess associating the instance of the bean that is still in the pool with the current HTTP session is meaningless.

Comment: See my response further below. The 2 instances 1st is the contextual instance, 2nd is the proxy. The @PostConstruct will of course only get called for the contextual instance and _not_ for the proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ryan, as covener already wrote, the constructor will also get called for each and every proxy for that bean. This is a standard behaviour of all proxy mechanisms which provide not only interface-proxying (like java.lang.reflect.proxy stuff) but real class-proxying.

Also imagine that the ct will also be called for each and every serialization. So if you work on a heavily load balanced cluster, you will see this lots of times. So please use @PostConstruct for beans in general.

LieGrue,
strub

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm still not understanding either of you though.  I'm aware of alternative ways to prepare a bean for use such as the PostConstruct lifecycle callback and the preRenderView system event; and that's great.  My question is why are two instances of a session scoped bean being created in a very simple test with only one user hitting the server.  I'm not talking about a heavy loaded server with load balancing and clustering.  Is more than one proxy being created?  If so, why?  Or maybe each proxy is backed by two instances of the bean?  If so, why?

Comment: Ryan, I know all the proxy stuff is not that easy, but getting 2 constructor invocations is perfectly fine.

1st instance is the contextual instance itself. This is the bean you will get stored in the SessionContext.

2nd instance is the proxy. If you look closely with the debugger or you print out the class in the constructor, then you will see that this is in fact a subclass of your bean!

Comment: One is the proxy and one is the actual bean.  Got it.   Seems like you must be careful what you put in a constructor when using CDI.

Comment: not only in CDI - also in Spring, EJB, JPA, etc. Basically in all frameworks which do some kind of proxying, serialisation and instance management in any form.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that your CDI implementation calls the underlying beans default constructor when newing up proxies to use for injection points -- this is the default behavior of javassist which is used in weld and openwebbeans.

Avoid heavy lifting in your default constructor, moving it into @PostConstruct if you can!

Comment: OK, but why are two being created?  Does CDI create a pool?